# MacOS Unity Build Issue

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, build-error

This is an issue about building a Unity project using a third party called MediapipeUnityPlugin. How can we solve this?

#### Unity Version

2021.3.18f1

---

#### Your Host OS

macOS Ventura 13.1

---

#### Log

Building Library/Bee/artifacts/MacStandalonePlayerBuildProgram/Features/Assembly-CSharp-FeaturesChecked.txt failed with output:
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library/Bee/artifacts/MacStandalonePlayerBuildProgram/Features/Assembly-CSharp-FeaturesChecked.txt

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
UnityEditorStartup/<>c:<.cctor>b__0_0 (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/XRPoster/Scripts/Editor/BuildProcessor.cs:9)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

---

BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/Modules/BeeBuildPostprocessor.cs:604)
UnityEditor.OSXStandalone.OSXDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/OSXPlayer/Extensions/Managed/OSXDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:117)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:28)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:370)
UnityEditor.DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions)
<>c:<.cctor>b__0_0(BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/XRPoster/Scripts/Editor/BuildProcessor.cs:9)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

---

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 5 seconds (4782 ms)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
UnityEditorStartup/<>c:<.cctor>b__0_0 (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) (at Assets/XRPoster/Scripts/Editor/BuildProcessor.cs:9)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

---

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ce] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:193
at UnityEditorStartup+<>c.<.cctor>b__0_0 (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions buildPlayerOptions) [0x00007] in /Users/youngjun/Desktop/unity-dev/XRPhotoBooth/Assets/XRPoster/Scripts/Editor/BuildProcessor.cs:9
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00072] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:92
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

---

#### List of history attempts to resolve build issues.

**1. Check the build modules included in the current Unity version**

- Android Build Support
- OpenJDK
- Android SDK & NDK Tools
- IOS Build Support
- Mac Build Support (IL2CPP)

**2. Check if multiple Unity processors are turned on : No problem**

**3. Reimport from Assets : No problem**

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue in the following way.

**Permission settings for the camera to be used in the app**

- Player Settings > Player > Mac Configuration > Camera Usage Description > "write description"